# Magento REST API: how to get custom table information in API?

Tags: api, custom, rest-api

How to create REST API which will fetch data from custom table?

Comment: Which version of Magento?

Comment: could you pls explain how you get values from the table by using API

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare new [service contract interface](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html), see [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html)
2. In the model implementing this interface read data from custom table (via resource model)
3. Expose created service contract interface as web API, see [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html)

Also might be useful to look at any core APIs as an example (e.g. `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`)